# How to disable Windows UAC totally, leaving no parts of its mechanism in memory?

Tags: windows-7, uac, performance-tuning

I know the question of disabling UAC is quite popular and has already been asked here, but my question is more specific. What I seek is not just to get UAC out of my way but to release all the system resources it might be consuming. The question is not about the behavioral aspect of UAC but about the code running for it to work.

I tend to believe that setting User Account Control settings to "Never notify" doesn't actually remove it completely - it is still, possibly, watching for the events and just ignoring them actively when it comes to. Regarding the policy-based methods I just have no idea.

So, may you be a Windows expert knowing exactly what is the code behind UAC, please be so kind to tell whether or not am I right in my guess and how to implement the solution.

Comment: Have you confirmed it's actually using system resources?  regardless, if you don't want _any_ UAC related code that might be using resources, then stop using Windows. :)

Comment: @techie007 I have read the question you've linked, it does not address my specific objective. There are many variants in the answers and what I am asking here is what particular answer does correspond to my criteria. Have you read my question details before voting to close it?

Comment: "if you don't want any UAC related code that might be using resources, then stop using Windows." - I was forced to switch to 7 from XP due to some special applications requirements. I'd be using XP gladly if it was a choice. And I do use GNU/Linux also.

Comment: The question I linked is "How can I completely disable UAC on Windows 7?". It specifies _completely_ removing it, so it's a duplicate question IMO. Otherwise, until you can point out specific "resources" you want to prevent it from using, I believe your question is mostly hypothetical and discussion oriented, both of which are considered off-topic for SU.  And remember, it takes votes 5 to close. :)

Answer (score 2):

What you want is impossible.
UAC is an integral part of the Windows kernel.
It has to be lowlevel in the kernel to be able to do what it does (monitoring system calls for access by programs that are NOT part of the kernelprocesses).

There is no way to remove it, except for a serious re-write of major parts of the NT kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Disable it from the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` Change `EnabledLUA` from 1 to 0